# Regex for string plus number range

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm using a regular expression to extract data from our reporting tool.

Here is the range:

```
cid=300000[195-429]
```

I tried `?cid=[300000195]-[300000429]`

But they are not working.

cid is part of the string. So, for example, return ?cid=300000197 and return ?cid=300000300

And everything in between.

What would be the correct regex syntax?

Comment: While I'm sure this can be done, regular expressions are not particularly good for this. Parse it out as a number and then ensure that the number is within the appropriate range.

Comment: I reiterate what @p.s.w.g said, regex isn't the best tool for numeric ranges. So whatever language your in, convert/cast the necessary range into `integers` and use your programming language of choice to determine if range is within bounds. Your example is just that, an example, remember maintainabile/readable code is far more important that doing nifty things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`cid=30000(19[5-9]|[2-3]\d{2}|4[0-2]\d)`

[Paste the regex here and give it a try.](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester)

Google Analytics' regular expression engine is rather weak compared to those used by Perl, PHP, JavaScript, and so on, so this took some tweaking. But as long as you're sure your URLs will be following the expected format, this should get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it's not actually working. It produces no data whereas when I check for specific numbers they do exist

Comment: Whoops! You're trying to extract those 3 numbers, that's right. I added a capturing group so that the 3-digit number is `match`ed by the expression. I also updated [the link.](http://regexr.com?3860k)

Comment: Nope :-(
We have many urls: example.com/?cid=300000195, example.com/?cid=300000196, example.com/?cid=300000197... all the way to 300. These urls appear in our Google Analytics reporting tool. I'd like to create a segment that pulls in any traffic that fits within that range. I tested your segment without any luck. Can it be done? Thanks all the same for trying to help out.

Comment: Are you testing the entire portion of the URL after the domain, question mark and all? If so, you might need to include the question mark in the regular expression. Is there anything else in the URL that could be messing it up?

Comment: (I edited the regex to include the question mark, which I just noticed was included in your question.) Also, in what language / platform are you using the regular expression?

Comment: It's within Google Analytics. There is a feature to segment traffic based on regex conditions. In this case I have said "Page (URL) matches regex \?cid=30000((?:19[5-9])|(?:[2-3]\d{2})|(?:4[0-2]\d))
So, here is an example URL that I'd want the regex to return:
/secure/auth?TYPE=[wholeBunchOfLongTextHere]HTTP://secure.example.com/secure/accountsummary/?cid=300000300&button=

Comment: Ahh, okay. I did some research on Google Analytics' regex engine. See my edits.

Comment: you are the best! I'm saving this little regex in my "useful formula and regex" list and will reuse it many many times - thanks a lot!